# App crashing during checking internet connectivity type

Tags: android

I have written code to check the network connectivity type as follows:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
NetworkInfo.State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();

//wifi
NetworkInfo.State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
```

I have also added the following permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But when I run the application it crashes. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Can you show us the errorlog ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these two permissions in your manifest file, if not add these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell the actual problem or solution as you haven't posted any error log. Though you can try this code.

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```